# alter http header with express for files in a folder or filetype?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

**Question:** With Express, How can I alter the maxAge header for only files within a certain sub-folder, or filetype (ie. Images only)

**I tried the following which did not work:**

```
// Setting the app router and static folder

var fiveDays = 432000000;

// Use maxAge 0 for everything
var app = express();
app.use(express.static(path.resolve('./public'), { maxAge: 0 }));

// only cache images for 5 days
app.use(express.static(path.resolve('./public/modules/core/img'), { maxAge: fiveDays }));

app.use(express.static(path.resolve('./public/modules/filters/img'), { maxAge: fiveDays }));

app.use(express.static(path.resolve('./public/modules/spotlights/img'), { maxAge: fiveDays }));

app.use(express.static(path.resolve('./public/modules/users/img'), { maxAge: fiveDays }));
```

**Result:**

All resources return back with maxAge = 0.

**Expected:**

Images would have a maxAge header of 432000000.

I know its possible calling use on two seperate folders, my problem is that the images I want to alter the header on are inside a sub folder of my main express.static call.

Answer (score 1):

**Ended up using the serve-static module to accomplish this based on mime-type:**

```
var serveStatic = require('serve-static');


app.use(serveStatic(path.resolve('./public'), {

  maxAge: '5d',

  setHeaders: setCustomCacheControl

}));





function setCustomCacheControl(res, path) {

  if (serveStatic.mime.lookup(path) === 'text/html') {

    // Custom Cache-Control for HTML files

    res.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'public, max-age=0')

  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is this is because every resource request is caught and processed by your first middleware. Have you tried putting this:

```
app.use(express.static(path.resolve('./public'), { maxAge: 0 }));
```

at the end of your snippet (after more specific mappings)?

Comment: I tried and it didn't seem to affect the maxAge header at all. I posted the solution with serve-static.